# How can I use `psql` without installing via brew

Tags: macos, postgresql, dylib, otool, install-name-tool

I want to use the `psql` utility standalone, without installing postgress via brew or something (I have my reasons). I use psql version 9.5.3 on OS X, which was distributed with PostgressApp.

When I only distribute psql, I get the error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _PQsslInUse
...
Expected in: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib
```

With the command `otool -L psql` I found path to the library was still pointing to Posgres.app, so I changed that with `install_name_tool` tool, and I also checked all referenced libraries and fixed them.

However, I still get the same error message. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Or another route to a working standalone `psql` binary?

Comment: The reason I want this, is I made an AppleScript library to communicate with Postgresql. This is the only reason I can't go live at the moment, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it here: https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues/338

The problem was I used install_name_tool not 100% correctly, and I forgot to create aliases.